# How do I go about resolving "package ‘ddply’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)"

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the package "ddply" but keep getting this response

> install.packages("ddply")
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘ddply’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: There is no `ddply` package.  It is a function from `plyr`  `install.packages('plyr')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ddply` is a function from the `plyr` package.  So, if we install the `plyr` package, it would work

```
install.packages('plyr')
```